# Subclipse shows dirty decorator even though project is up to date

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I have an eclipse project with which I'm using subversion and subclipse. Currently the top level folder of the project is showing the dirty decorator even though when I do a "Compare With->Latest from Repository" the response is "There are no differences between the selected inputs." Furthermore, an "svn diff " from the command line shows no differences.

Here's a transcript:

```
[ollie@devdataload workspace]$ svn diff DataLoadEagleOliver

Property changes on: DataLoadEagleOliver
___________________________________________________________________
Added: svn:mergeinfo
   Merged /FinancialReport/trunk/Java/DataLoadEagle:r1178-1186

[ollie@devdataload workspace]$
```

Is this expected behavior and I'm missing something or is this a know issue with subclipse?

I'm using subclipse 1.6.18 and Eclipse Indigo. The next thing I'm going to try is upgrading subclipse to the latest version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `svn diff` does show a difference: the `svn:mergeinfo` property. This might not show up when you do Compare With, but it is a difference, and you should probably commit it.

That property is automatically changed whenever you merge from another branch. It keeps track of which revisions have already been merged, so it can skip them the next time you merge from the same branch.

Answer (score 2):

The commit or revert options are good ways to see which paths have changes.  When the change is only to a property, those dialogs will have a decorator to show this.  The Eclipse compare options are focused on file content so you cannot really see property differences in those editors.